# How to 'select distinct on' as a subquery using django filters

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, filter

I'm creating a search function for my django project and was wondering how I can group rows while ordering them by the amount of points the players have scored.

I want to be able to group them and when it finds values with the same name, it just takes the first value

The solution I found on postgresql

```
select * from 
(select distinct on (name) * from database_manager_player) t
order by pts desc;
```

database values:

| name | team | pts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| andrew | A | 20 |
| andrew | B | 24 |
| andrew | C | 12 |
| jones | B | 8 |
| jones | C | 6 |

expected result after query:

| name | team | pts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| andrew | A | 20 |
| jones | B | 8 |

I wanted to know if there was a way to code something similar in django.

in views.py:

```
    def get_queryset(self):
            qs = Player.objects.all().order_by('-pts')
            sort_by = self.request.GET.get("sort")
            if sort_by is not None and sort_by != str(0)
                sort_by = "-" + sort_by 
                # query here
```

with 'qs' how could I do something in the if statement so that it does the same as  in postgresql.

Comment: Please add a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. You can start with adding small data samples of you source data and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select distinct on, you have to use a subquery

```
 ids = qs.distinct("name").order_by().values_list("pk", flat=True)
 qs = qs.filter(pk__in=ids)
```